# CSS overflow-x hidden also hides vertical

Tags: html, css, overflow

There are endless questions on SO that are very similar but none of which have solved my problem.

I have multiple sections that have top and bottom margins and inner elements that overflow horizontally, for example...

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

section:before {
  content: 'This overflows...';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 110vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you can see from the above, the red box causes overflow-x to scroll, however, I want this element to still overflow but hidden.

I assumed adding `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible;` to the `<section>` would fix this...

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

section:before {
  content: 'This overflows...';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 110vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Card 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id luctus mi, tempor varius ligula. Nunc pharetra et velit vitae tristique. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But this clips the shadows...

[image]

Obviously switching from margins to paddings would fix this but it also doubles the space between the two sections so the use of margins is a must.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd need `width: 110vw;` when it is creating the overflow in the first place and you don't want the overflow and scroll. Changing it to `width: 100vw;` eliminates the overflow and horizontal scroll. Was there a specific reason for `110vw`?

Comment: In any case, replacing `margin: 100px 0;` with `padding-bottom: 100px;` will solve your cut-off issue and maintain the spacing between `section`s. Then you could optionally add a `margin-top: 100;` to `section:first-of-type` if you need the top spacing as well.

Comment: @BumhanYu thank you for your thoughts. The actual setup is a lot more complex but I have simplified it for the sake of this question. The width 110vw is just there to simulate the overflow.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your clarification. As mentioned in my second comment, perhaps a combination of `padding-bottom` and `margin-top` or/and an adjacent selector `section + section` might help?